# Why is display:block; not causing this <a> tag to fill all available area inside this <div>?

Tags: html, css, anchor

Here's my HTML:

```html
            <div id="food-selector">
                <div>
                    <div id="left-selector-arrow">
                        <div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="current-selection">
                        <p>SPINACH</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right-selector-arrow">
                        <div>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here's my CSS (LESS):

```css
    #food-selector {
        position: relative;
        top: -50px;
        left: 22px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 55px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        div {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;

            div, a {
                float: left;
            }

            #left-selector-arrow {
                .sprite(8,0,30px,34px);

                div {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    float: none;

                    a {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }

            #current-selection {
                .sprite(5,0,143px,34px);
                line-height: 34px;

                p {
                    padding: 7px 12px;
                    margin: 0;
                    .futuraBold;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
            }

            #right-selector-arrow {
                .sprite(9,0,30px,34px);

                div {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    float: none;

                    a {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the result is that the anchor tag has a height and width of "0px" so it isn't taking up any space at all, and as such isn't making the boxes clickable.

Any ideas? I understood that applying `display:block;` to an anchor tag should have caused it to fill the entire contents of its parent `div`, but not in this case apparently...

Comment: Can you post the rendered CSS and if not, add the LESS tag to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is completely jacked up.  Your href will only take up the space you define for it (aka line height and the length of the string of text you are linking).  If you'd like for it to take up the full div then your containing div should have a width and height and then the link should be set to width: 100%; height: 100%;

So if the only thing you are defining is the food id then it won't work.  You'll have to define the divs around the anchor.

Here is a JS fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pwym7/

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"><a href="#" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">WORDS</a></div>
```

Comment: The containing div does have a height and width; 30px (w) 34px (h)

The <a> now has 100% width and height, and still doesn't take up the space of the `div`.